# Extend A View With Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, razor, thymeleaf

is it possible extend a shared view with **thymeleaf**?

I saw that is possible use **[framents](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#template-layout)** but is not what I want.
Instead I want something similar to .NET MVC, with something like **@RenderBody()** and another view that extend the shared view by including the shared view.

Comment: [This worked for me. I hope this works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54638996/5468982)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [Thymeleaf Layout Dialect](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect) to extend a view.

**Layout page**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    ...
    <body layout:fragment="body">
      ...
    </body>
</html>
```

**Content page**

In your content page, you refer to the layout (decorator) page using the `layout:decorator` attribute.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorator="layout.html">
    ...
    <body layout:fragment="body">
      <p>Actual page content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is possible to have multiple fragments in one page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    ...
    <body>
      <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
      <footer layout:fragment="footer"></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will use Rythm instead Thymeleaf. It is a lot faster and with more functionality. https://github.com/greenlaw110/spring-rythm

Comment: Rythm is a general template engine, while Thymeleaf is an XML/XHTML/HTML5 template engine. Rythm may be faster, but the cost of rendering a view is negligible nowadays. Thymeleaf would provide you cleaner templates and template validation, which increases productivity. But whatever floats your boat :).

Comment: I understand. By the way Rythm has been developed from one of my actual colleague.

Comment: Awesome!! Layout Dialect is exactly what I need. I'm happy I don't need to employ Tiles.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like as for the Thymeleaf version 3.1 template extension is supposed to be done using the other mechanism described in [Tutorial: Using Thymeleaf (3.1.2.RELEASE), chapter 8.5 Layout Inheritance](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#layout-inheritance):

The layout is (`src/main/resources/templates/layout/layout_simple.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" th:fragment="layout(title, main)"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title th:replace="${title}">Layout title</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Common block: header</header>
<main id="mainpart" th:replace="${main}">
    <p><em>This content must not be visible.</em></p>
</main>
<footer>Common block: footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The page is (`src/main/resources/templates/thymeleaf_first_page_simple.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html th:replace="~{layout/layout_simple :: layout(~{::title}, ~{::main})}"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Thymeleaf demo simple</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <h1>Thymeleaf template extension simple demo</h1>
    <p>Actual page content: [<th:block th:text="${modelValue}" />]</p>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Thymeleaf demo simple</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Common block: header</header>
<main>
    <h1>Thymeleaf template extension simple demo</h1>
    <p>Actual page content: [some simple value from the model]</p>
</main>
<footer>Common block: footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to make it so it doesn't include the element it's selecting in `~{::main}`? The base HTML that I want to replace into the layout is more than one element, how do I grab everything i need

Comment: Nevermind, apparently you can have multiple `th:fragment="content"`